# Lan speed stuck on 100Mb/s

Tags: 14.04, atheros, lan

I cant get 1000Mb/s speed on my lan card. below is my specs :

```
laptop : toshiba satellite L50-A, core i3
######################
sudo ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  Not reported
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: No
    Speed: 100Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: off
    MDI-X: Unknown
    Current message level: 0x000060e4 (24804)
                   link ifup rx_err tx_err hw wol
####################
sudo lshw -C network
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 10
       serial: 00:8c:fa:90:7a:28
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx duplex=full ip=10.249.10.24 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:47 memory:c5500000-c553ffff ioport:2000(size=128)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 48:d2:24:2e:13:94
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.16.0-31-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:17 memory:c5400000-c547ffff memory:c5480000-c548ffff
#########################
sudo ethtool -s eth0 speed 1000 duplex full
Cannot set new settings: Invalid argument
  not setting speed
  not setting duplex
###########################
 uname -a
Linux work 3.16.0-31-generic #43~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 10 20:13:38 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
#############################
```

I use ubuntu 14.04.2LTS fresh install, i even turn off the autoneg

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Did you try another cable? Does the other end of the connection support Gigabit? Note how `lshw` says `size: 100Mbit/s`, but capacity is 1Gbit/s - that means Ubuntu sees gigabit capability, but other things in the connection restrict it.

Comment: yea i change the cable and even test it with another laptop and it got 1000Mb/s, i check on the laptop website and on its specs it says that it support 1000Mb/s, i have a dlink gigabit lan switch i test the port on another laptop and it works well on 1000Mb/s. i think that the alx driver is crappy